# Sass / Compass sprites

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

hi all i have some issue with generating sprite file, i want to add new files at the end of the file but compass adds new files alphabetically and then all positions are changing, how to force compass to add files at the end of the sprite file

SASS

```
$sprite-spacing: 20px;
$sprite-layout: horizontal;
@import "sprite/*.png";
@include all-sprite-sprites;
```

CONFIG

```
on_sprite_saved do |filename|
  if File.exists?(filename)
    FileUtils.cp filename, filename.gsub(%r{-s[a-z0-9]{10}\.png$}, '.png')
  end
end

on_stylesheet_saved do |filename|
  if File.exists?(filename)
    css = File.read filename
    File.open(filename, 'w+') do |f|
      f << css.gsub(%r{-s[a-z0-9]{10}\.png}, '.png')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you care about sprite positions? Do you set background position manually?

Comment: yes a prefer that than using addintionl class names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set background positions manually. You can do that automatically without having Compass generate classes.

Say, you have the following sprites:

- images/

  - social/

    - facebook.png
    - twitter.png

SASS updated according to @piouPiouM's suggestoin:

```
$social-sprite-dimensions: true
@import "social/*.png";

#my-semantic-selector {
  @include social-sprite(facebook);
}

#another .semantic > selector {
  @include social-sprite(twitter);
}
```

This results in the following clean CSS:

```
.social-sprite, #my-semantic-selector, #another .semantic > selector {
  background: url('/images/social-sa75ff48010.png') no-repeat;
}

#my-semantic-selector {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 25px;
}

#another .semantic > selector {
  background-position: 0 -25px;
  width: 27px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

It is possible to write a more universal mixin that allows for multiple sprite collections. It will need Compass [sprite helpers](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/sprites/) and [sprite base](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/sprites/base/). If multiple sprite collections is a requirement for you and you need an example, please tell so in comments.

Comment: @andrey-lolmaus-mikhaylov creating a new mixin is useless. Set `$<map>-sprite-dimensions: true` before importing the sprite map. Then simply use the mixin `<map>-sprite(<sprite>)`, like `social-sprite(twitter)`, to generate the properties `background-position`, `width` and `height`.

Comment: Great catch, @piouPiouM! I've been using that myself but i thought that the variable is being evaluated by the `all-<map>-sprites` mixin, not map import. Thank you for the suggestion, i've updated the code accordingly.